# Google Sheet Query not returning all rows from a separate tab

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I'm writing this syntax:

=QUERY('Business Case'!A4:R41,"SELECT D,E,H,I,J,L,M,R WHERE 1=1 "&" AND LOWER (J) LIKE LOWER('%" &JOIN("%') AND LOWER (J) LIKE LOWER ('%", SPLIT(A64," "))&"%')",0)

The data field ( 'Business Case'!A4:R41) is correct but it does not reflect the bottom rows of the Business Case Sheet.

I couldn't understand what was wrong with it. I used the same formula with another query from a different sheet, and it worked. But this one does not.

Comment: `SPLIT(A64," ")` may cause problem. Share a sample workbook so that we can check it.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output